# issue with database connection in Rails worker process using PostGIS on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, postgis, worker

I am trying to use a combination of PostGIS (RGeo) and Sidekiq to process long running jobs asynchronously in a Heroku environment. Unfortunately, it seems the Rails worker process that runs Sidekiq jobs (bundle exec sidekiq) does not completely honor the settings in database.yml. In Heroku, the database connection is provided via the DATABASE_URL environment variable and is read-only.  For Rails apps that use PostGIS, the database.yml file has to change the scheme on this url from postgres to postgis, as in the following example.

database.yml

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL", "").gsub(/postgres/, 'postgis') %>
  ...
```

Here's how I have sidekiq configured to run as a worker process

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
worker: jemalloc.sh bundle exec sidekiq -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} -c ${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY:-5}
```

When I run rails console and check the database url, it is correct (uses the postgis scheme)

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.url
=> "postgis://abc:xyz@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/asdf"
```

However, if I log the same thing from a sidekiq job, it is not correct

```
Rails.logger.info("Database URL => #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.url}")

postgres://abc:xyz@xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/asdf
```

This causes errors when trying load models that use a geometry type.  First you see something like

```
unknown OID 31594: failed to recognize type of 'coords'. It will be treated as String.
```

Then you will get errors trying to access properties of the geometry

```
undefined method `x' for \"0101000020E61000000C570740DC1E55C0BEF561BD51054140\":String
```

I have found that this hack in the Procfile gets the correct configuration value into the worker process and works around the issue, but it duplicates the logic and shouldn't be required.

```
worker: DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL/postgres/postgis} jemalloc.sh bundle exec sidekiq -e ${RACK_ENV:-development} -c ${SIDEKIQ_CONCURRENCY:-5}
```

Anyone have a method to get worker processes in Heroku to use the database.yml correctly?